# creating function in TikZ that can break up and interpret string

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I find myself needing to draw a bunch of simple patterns with a few colors, as in the example below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]
\draw[style=help lines,step=1cm] (-2.3,-2.3) grid (2.3,2.3);
\draw[fill=green] (-2,1) rectangle (-1,2);
\draw[fill=red] (-1,1) rectangle (0,2);
\draw[fill=blue] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);
\draw[fill=yellow] (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

\draw[fill=red] (-2,0) rectangle (-1,1);
\draw[fill=green] (-1,0) rectangle (0,1);
\draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[fill=blue] (1,0) rectangle (2,1);    

\draw[fill=yellow] (-2,-1) rectangle (-1,0);
\draw[fill=blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (0,0);
\draw[fill=red] (0,-1) rectangle (1,0);
\draw[fill=green] (1,-1) rectangle (2,0);    

\draw[fill=blue] (-2,-2) rectangle (-1,-1);
\draw[fill=red] (-1,-2) rectangle (0,-1);
\draw[fill=green] (0,-2) rectangle (1,-1);
\draw[fill=yellow] (1,-2) rectangle (2,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Output]

This is clearly an inefficient way of creating the picture though, and would ideally like to have a function `rowpatternmaker coords string` so that
`rowpatternmaker (-2,0) rgyb` would create a row of coloured squares starting from (-2,0) which, from left to right, are red, green, yellow, blue. In this way, I could then create the pattern above with

```
rowpatternmaker (-2,1) grby
rowpatternmaker (-2,0) rgyb
rowpatternmaker (-2,-1) ybrg
rowpatternmaker (-2,-2) brgy
```

Of course, what I'd really like is to make a function `square pattern maker` where

```
squarepatternmaker (-2,1) grby rgyb ybrg brgy
```

would create the pattern above.

While I've created a few figures with TikZ, I'm unsure of how to create a function like this, let along one that can read a string "grby" and interpret this as a list of colours.

Assuming it's possible, how would I go about creating `rowpatternmaker` (or `squarepatternmaker`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having bare words as commands is unnecessarily hard in LaTeX.  That is why I introduce

```
\rowpatternmaker (-2,1) grby;
\rowpatternmaker (-2,0) rgyb;
\rowpatternmaker (-2,-1) ybrg;
\rowpatternmaker (-2,-2) brgy;
```

I hope that's okay.  The first argument is the starting coordinate and the second is the color sequence.  If you leave the color sequence empty it will default to `rgby`.  The line length is determined by the length of the color sequence, i.e. `rgbrgb` will be six long.

The square pattern maker is also possible

```
\squarepatternmaker (-2,1) grby rgyb ybrg brgy;
```

It is implement in terms of the row pattern maker.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_cookie_rows_seq
\int_new:N \l_cookie_rowcount_int
\seq_new:N \l_cookie_colors_seq
\int_new:N \l_cookie_count_int

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cookie_map_colors:Nn #1#2
 {
  \seq_clear:N #1
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \str_case:nn { ##1 }
     {
      { r } { \seq_put_right:Nn #1 { red } }
      { g } { \seq_put_right:Nn #1 { green } }
      { b } { \seq_put_right:Nn #1 { blue } }
      { y } { \seq_put_right:Nn #1 { yellow } }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cookie_row_pattern_maker:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \cookie_map_colors:Nn \l_cookie_colors_seq { #3 }
  \int_zero:N \l_cookie_count_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_cookie_colors_seq
   {
    \draw[fill=##1] (#1+\int_use:N \l_cookie_count_int,#2) rectangle +(1,1);
    \int_incr:N \l_cookie_count_int
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rowpatternmaker (#1,#2) #3;
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #3 }
   { \cookie_row_pattern_maker:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { rgby } }
   { \cookie_row_pattern_maker:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \cookie_square_pattern_maker:nnn #1#2#3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_cookie_rows_seq { ~ } { \tl_trim_spaces:n { #3 } }
  \int_zero:N \l_cookie_rowcount_int
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_cookie_rows_seq
   {
    \cookie_row_pattern_maker:nnn { #1 } { #2 - \int_use:N \l_cookie_rowcount_int } { ##1 }
    \int_incr:N \l_cookie_rowcount_int
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \squarepatternmaker (#1,#2) #3;
 {
  \cookie_square_pattern_maker:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm] (-2.3,-2.3) grid (2.3,2.3);
  \rowpatternmaker (-2,1) grby;
  \rowpatternmaker (-2,0) rgyb;
  \rowpatternmaker (-2,-1) ybrg;
  \rowpatternmaker (-2,-2) brgy;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[style=help lines,step=1cm] (-2.3,-2.3) grid (2.3,2.3);
  \squarepatternmaker (-2,1) grby rgyb ybrg brgy;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]